# How to do column multiplication with NAs in dataframe?

Tags: r, na, missing-data

For example if this is the df I have.

`df<-data.frame(a=c(1,0,1,1,0), b=c(1,NA,NA,3,5),c=c(NA,2,4,NA,NA))`

```
df  
  a  b  c
  1  1 NA
  0 NA  2
  1 NA  4
  1  3 NA
  0  5 NA
```

I'd like to create a function that will multiply both `b` and `c` columns with a scalar 2 when the value in column `a` equals 1, and multiply both `b` and `c` columns with a scalar 4 when the value in column `a` equals 0.
In addition, I don't want to remove any of the NAs or convert them to 0, so all NA cells should remind the same. The expected result looks like this.

```
  a  b  c
  1  2 NA
  0 NA  8
  1 NA  8
  1  6 NA
  0 20 NA
```

I tried to use na.rm or na.omit, but they don't really meet my need. Any help on this would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try with `ifelse` or `case_when` (from `dplyr`) i.e. `df %>% mutate_at(vars(b, c), funs(case_when(a==1~ .*2, TRUE ~ .*4)))`  Note that any number multiplied by NA returns NA

Comment: Or in base R `df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(i) ifelse(df$a == 1, i*2, i*4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df$a==0,-1]=df[df$a==0,-1]*4
df[df$a==1,-1]=df[df$a==1,-1]*2
 df
  a  b  c
1 1  2 NA
2 0 NA  8
3 1 NA  8
4 1  6 NA
5 0 20 NA
```